# What is the format of "dataset" used as a parameter of the grid.py script?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am new at svm world and have following question:

The python script for searching for the best combination of C and gamma must be called as following:

```
 grid.py [grid_options] [svm_options] dataset
```

So how does dataset look like: is it a serialization of the training matrix? Does one have to produce it using the tools in libsvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibSVM shares a text format for datasets with SVMlight and a few other machine learning tools, which in the simplest form contains lines such as

```
0 2:0.9 3:0.1
1 1:1.0 2:-1
```

to describe a target vector `[0 1]` and two sample vectors

```
[0.0   0.9  0.1]
[1.0  -1.0  0.0]
```

[Examples](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/) can be found on the LibSVM website.